# Volume of z = 1-xy using iterated integrals

Tags: integration, volume, iterated-integrals

ok so the question asks for the volume of the function

$z = 1-xy$ on the first octant bounded by

$x = y$ and $x = y^2  $

i know that on the interval $x = y$ is greater than $x = y^2$ so the limits look like $$\int_0^1\int_{y^2}^y$$ (the intersection on first octant) 
NOTE: my integration using dA = dx dy 
however, when i evaluate this iterated integral i am returned with
 $V=-0.5417$ ?

ive checked the graph of this and it looks like the volume should be positive with the given boundaries. I know that double integrals are not always equal to the iterated but my prof said for her questions it should be. What am i doing wrong? is the outer bound supposed to be from 1 to 0 instead to yield a positive volume, but how come thats the case?

here's my work but idk how to format integral symbol on here
V = integral form 0 to  1 of (-y - ((y^3)/2) + ((y^5)/2) )dy which gives 
V = -0.5417

Comment: Show us how you got $-0.5417.$

Comment: Note that the bound of the integral for $dy$ are actually $\int_{x^2}^x$.
Also here is [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1-x*y,%7Bx,0,1%7D,%7By,x%5E2,x%7D%5D) result.

Comment: i am using dA = dx dy   so my inner integral is at dx

Comment: also if ur using dy as the inner integral wouldnt the bound be from x to positive root of x?

Comment: @Zubzub That's wrong - the values are $y^2\leq x\leq y$, not $x^2\leq y\leq x$. (Although by symmetry, it doesn't really matter which region you choose.)

Comment: Thank you all i noticed my derp on the algebra now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\overbrace{\left(\int_0^1 dx \int_{x^2}^x dy\ 1\right)}^A - \overbrace{\left(\int_0^1 dx \int_{x^2}^x dy\ xy \right)}^B
$$

$$
A = \int_0^1 (x -x^2)\ dx = \left[\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{3} \right]_0^1 = \frac12 - \frac13
$$
$$
B = \int_0^1 x \frac12 (x^2 - x^4)\ dx = \frac12 \left[\frac{x^4}{4} -\frac{x^6}{6} \right]_0^1 = \frac12(\frac14 - \frac16)
$$
Combining all gives you $\frac18$